# Existing Website to support Node.js web server

Tags: node.js

I have developed a simple website in php. I use WAMP server to run the website. As I am new to Node.js environment, I found that we can create Node.js Web Server and run our webpages on it. 
Is it possible to run my php webpages on Node.js Web Server? How can i make my php webpages to run on Node.js Web Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not run PHP through Node.js. Usually you would use your existing web server (that you use for PHP) as a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).